# How to get elements of arrayList from servlet to jsp and display on the same jsp without using AJAX

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, arraylist

This is my servlet code

```
 con.getCliWithProp(fromdate, todate, packageid, quantity,pro);
        for(int i=0;i<Integer.parseInt(quantity);i++){
            results.add(con.resultCli.toArray()[i].toString());

        }System.out.println(results);
        request.setAttribute("cli",results);
    }
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/npt.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
```

I am getting this arralyList in a jsp, and my JSP code is

```
<form action="getDetails" method="post">
<label>From date</label>
<input type="text" name="fromDate" placeholder="From Date" id="datepicker">
<label>To date</label>
<input type="text" name="toDate" placeholder="To Date" id="datepicker1">
<br>
<button class="btn btn-success"  id='submit' >Generate CLI</button>

 </form>
 <br><br>
 <div id="display">
 <pre>
 <font size="4">${requestScope.cli}</font>
 </pre>
 </div>
```

when I give from date and to date, it fetches me the data in an arrayList but displays it in the format like

```
['122131232','123232312']
```

I want to display them element wise on that same jsp page without using AJAX.

Comment: You are seeing so because its simply printing `results.toString()`. When you say _I want to display them element wise_ shows by example how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you only want to get length of a Collection use `fn:length(tableEntity.rows))`

and for the purpose of iterating use JSTL `<c:forEach>`

```
<c:forEach items='${List}' var='varObj'>
<c:out value="${varObj}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: is it possible if i want to pick those values separately and display then inside a table ??? will <C:forEach> can be used for that ???

Comment: you can place your table inside <c:forEach> and then use <c:out value=${varObj} /> to display.

Answer (score 1):

To display it element wise, use JSTL `<c:forEach/>` tag,

```
<div id="display">
    <pre>
     <c:forEach items=${requestScope.cli} var="item">
     <font size="4">${item}</font> <br />
     </c:forEach>
    </pre>
</div>
```

To use ajax, use JQuery ajax with Servlet and JSON,

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button').click(function() {
         $.get('JsonStrListServlet', function(responseJson) {   
         // Parse the json result on somediv
          var $ul = $('<ul>').appendTo($('#somediv')); 
          $.each(responseJson, function(index, item) {
          $('<li>').text(item).appendTo($ul);  
          });
      });

  });
</script>
```

Comment: am getting an error when i try to use prefix c, i added this line on the top of the page 
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

Comment: yeah i added it inspite of adding that also am getting an error stating

"Can not find the tag library descriptor." something like this shows up

Comment: @user2766041, Probably JSTL jar file is missing at your class path.

Comment: is it possible if i want to pick those values separately and display then inside a table ??? will <C:forEach> can be used for that ???